# Sequencing of dictionaries in list according to one of the value in it

Tags: python-3.x

With the list of dictionaries given below

```
 sample_dict = [{'Time':10, 'Name':'Loc1'},
                {'Time':,9 'Name':'Loc2'},
                {'Time':7, 'Name':'Loc3'},
                {'Time':6, 'Name':'Loc4'},
                {'Time':2, 'Name':'Loc5'}]
```

Where `Name` is name of the location and `Time` is the time taken to service that location. Now i want to assign tasks for these locations to 2,3,4 employees so that the total time consumption is least.

For eg in case of 2 employees.

```
task_assigned_to_emp1 = {'Time':10, 'Name':'Loc1'} & {'Time':7, 'Name':'Loc3'}

total_time_taken_by_emp1 = 17

task_assigned_to_emp2 = {'Time':,9 'Name':'Loc2'} & {'Time':6, 'Name':'Loc4'}           & {'Time':2, 'Name':'Loc5'}

total_time_taken_by_emp2 = 17
```

Similarly with 3 & 4 number of employees.

Also the output should have a sequence like mentioned below.

```
output = [{'Time':10, 'Name':'Loc1', 'Sequecne':1},
          {'Time':,9 'Name':'Loc2', 'Sequecne':2},
          {'Time':7, 'Name':'Loc3', 'Sequecne':4},
          {'Time':6, 'Name':'Loc4', 'Sequecne':3},
          {'Time':2, 'Name':'Loc5', 'Sequecne':5}]
```

Output explanation

`emp1` and `emp2` were given `Loc1` and `Loc2`. `Emp2` returned earlier than `emp1` cause his/her task took 9 mins while `emp1's` task took 10 mins. So we gave `Loc4` to `emp2` and then `emp1` came and was assigned `Loc3` and lastly `emp2` was assigned `Loc5`.

Comment: Hello, this is a NP completness algorithm, and SO is not for this kind of questions, you should try to code it yourself, and come back if you have technical errors

Comment: Ok, now what's your question actually ? What have you tried and where are you stuck ?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken can't this be done iteratively? Looking for all the possible solution and choosing the best possible solution from it

Comment: This is one of the possible solutions. Just try it out and try to optimize it afterwards, SO is just not for this kind of questions without technical difficulties

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers as of now i have just sorted the dict sequentially by max time taken. sample_dict has info of locations like its name and time taken to service that locations. Now i want to assign these locations first according to 2 employees and assign tasks in a way that these 2 employees should service these locations in minimum time possible

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers have tried using greedy algorithm which gives output with difference of 2 mins.

Comment: And ? Really, _what's your question ?_  NB : If you're asking for a ready-made solution then you're at the wrong place.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers well the best solution for the mentioned example has difference of 0. Not looking for ready made solution, just the methods that can be used.

Comment: @python_user "methods that can be used" is  still quite vague. Please edit your post to add 1/ what you've done so far and why it doesn't work, and 2/ a _clear, unambiguous question_.